# How to extract a table from a text file with lots of explanation lines in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, io, text-files

I have a text file and want to extract the table inside it in MatLab. The problem is that there are two many lines of explanations before the table. I've tried `importdata`, `readtable` and `textscan` but I did not manage to solve the problem. I did read similar posts, however, they did not work for me. All I want is to get the table inside it.

This is my text file and I just want to get the table:

```
    # Title Segmentation Statistics 
    # 
    # generating_program mri_segstats
    # cvs_version $Id: mri_segstats.c,v 1.121 2016/05/31 17:27:11 greve Exp $
    # cmdline mri_segstats --annot s99060003 lh aparc --i ./ghorbani/s99060003/surf/lh.pial_lgi --sum ./ghorbani/s99060003/stats/lh.aparc.pial_lgi.stats 
    # sysname  Linux
    # hostname computational01
    # machine  x86_64
    # user     team47
    # anatomy_type surface
    # 
    # SUBJECTS_DIR ghorbani/
    # subjectname s99060003
    # Annot s99060003 lh aparc
    # ColorTable /tmp/mri_segstats.tmp.s99060003.lh.107.ctab 
    # ColorTableTimeStamp 2020/11/11 12:29:40 
    # InVolFile  ./ghorbani/s99060003/surf/lh.pial_lgi 
    # InVolFileTimeStamp  2020/11/09 13:22:36 
    # InVolFrame 0 
    # Only reporting non-empty segmentations
    # VertexArea_mm2 0.651303 
    # TableCol  1 ColHeader Index 
    # TableCol  1 FieldName Index 
    # TableCol  1 Units     NA 
    # TableCol  2 ColHeader SegId 
    # TableCol  2 FieldName Segmentation Id
    # TableCol  2 Units     NA
    # TableCol  3 ColHeader NVertices 
    # TableCol  3 FieldName Number of Vertices
    # TableCol  3 Units     unitless
    # TableCol  4 ColHeader Area_mm2
    # TableCol  4 FieldName Area
    # TableCol  4 Units     mm^2
    # TableCol  5 ColHeader StructName
    # TableCol  5 FieldName Structure Name
    # TableCol  5 Units     NA
    # TableCol  6 ColHeader Mean 
    # TableCol  6 FieldName Intensity Mean
    # TableCol  6 Units     unknown
    # TableCol  7 ColHeader StdDev
    # TableCol  7 FieldName Itensity StdDev
    # TableCol  7 Units     unknown
    # TableCol  8 ColHeader Min
    # TableCol  8 FieldName Intensity Min
    # TableCol  8 Units     unknown
    # TableCol  9 ColHeader Max
    # TableCol  9 FieldName Intensity Max
    # TableCol  9 Units     unknown
    # TableCol 10 ColHeader Range
    # TableCol 10 FieldName Intensity Range
    # TableCol 10 Units     unknown
    # NRows 35 
    # NTableCols 10 
    # ColHeaders  Index SegId NVertices Area_mm2 StructName Mean StdDev Min Max Range  
      1 1000      8260     5272.3  unknown                            2.5699     0.3767     1.7473     3.1269     1.3796 
      2 1001      1636     1125.1  bankssts                           3.7293     0.0772     3.5467     3.9301     0.3833 
      3 1002      1050      710.4  caudalanteriorcingulate            2.0687     0.0944     1.8839     2.2960     0.4121 
      4 1003      3758     2416.2  caudalmiddlefrontal                3.3097     0.2763     2.7127     3.8032     1.0905 
      5 1005      2166     1394.6  cuneus                             2.9522     0.1720     2.4722     3.1704     0.6982 
      6 1006      1174      792.0  entorhinal                         2.7577     0.1658     2.4730     3.0749     0.6019 
      7 1007      5212     3492.8  fusiform                           2.7802     0.1668     2.3861     3.0655     0.6794 
      8 1008      7868     5244.3  inferiorparietal                   3.4037     0.2220     2.7239     3.7361     1.0122 
      9 1009      6358     4246.9  inferiortemporal                   2.8457     0.2358     2.3203     3.5561     1.2358 
     10 1010      1697     1039.9  isthmuscingulate                   2.6552     0.1808     2.1455     2.9743     0.8288 
     11 1011      7550     4798.7  lateraloccipital                   2.5837     0.2590     2.2416     3.5063     1.2648 
     12 1012      4240     2810.9  lateralorbitofrontal               2.7308     0.6746     2.0304     4.6397     2.6094 
     13 1013      4358     2954.4  lingual                            2.8151     0.1788     2.3492     3.0892     0.7401 
     14 1014      3642     2336.4  medialorbitofrontal                2.2751     0.1566     2.0293     2.7523     0.7230 
     15 1015      5003     3347.4  middletemporal                     3.5771     0.4750     2.5574     4.8942     2.3368 
     16 1016      1296      853.5  parahippocampal                    2.9505     0.0971     2.6101     3.1791     0.5691 
     17 1017      2216     1350.9  paracentral                        2.4485     0.1490     2.1895     2.7342     0.5448 
     18 1018      2341     1540.7  parsopercularis                    4.3045     0.4102     3.6751     4.9626     1.2874 
     19 1019      1210      824.4  parsorbitalis                      3.3446     0.5123     2.6070     4.5994     1.9923 
     20 1020      2107     1401.6  parstriangularis                   4.2211     0.4835     3.0488     4.8220     1.7732 
     21 1021      1860     1287.3  pericalcarine                      2.7804     0.2588     2.3185     3.1067     0.7882 
     22 1022      7271     4522.0  postcentral                        3.5938     0.4878     2.5672     5.1158     2.5486 
     23 1023      1931     1239.0  posteriorcingulate                 2.2056     0.1836     1.8830     2.6753     0.7923 
     24 1024      8666     5120.9  precentral                         3.4961     0.6538     2.2783     5.1111     2.8327 
     25 1025      5709     3855.1  precuneus                          2.9406     0.1734     2.4881     3.2976     0.8096 
     26 1026      1755     1161.3  rostralanteriorcingulate           2.2062     0.0809     1.9160     2.3647     0.4486 
     27 1027      9874     6494.3  rostralmiddlefrontal               2.9003     0.4655     2.0864     3.9290     1.8426 
     28 1028     11653     7628.0  superiorfrontal                    2.2950     0.2455     1.9748     3.1270     1.1521 
     29 1029      9400     6171.7  superiorparietal                   3.2156     0.2676     2.6601     3.7812     1.1212 
     30 1030      5557     3690.8  superiortemporal                   4.3597     0.5310     2.5410     5.1207     2.5797 
     31 1031      6830     4433.7  supramarginal                      3.7339     0.2066     3.4023     4.5124     1.1101 
     32 1032       433      292.9  frontalpole                        2.1079     0.0319     2.0224     2.2147     0.1924 
     33 1033       661      454.8  temporalpole                       2.5558     0.0856     2.3724     2.8309     0.4585 
     34 1034       695      431.5  transversetemporal                 4.7385     0.1794     4.3918     5.0519     0.6601 
     35 1035      3891     2520.8  insula                             4.4928     0.7830     2.5227     5.1226     2.6000
```

Comment: Please paste (a piece of ) the file contents instead of inserting a screenshot.

Comment: I pasted the text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `'HeaderLines'` to skip a fixed number of line, when reading file by [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html).

For example to read the file with following contents:

> some
> extra
> lines
> come
> here
> 1,2
> 3,4

, you can run:

```
readtable('data.txt', 'HeaderLines', 5, 'Delimiter', ',')
```

It will return:

> ans =
>
> ```
> Var1    Var2
> ____    ____
>
> 1       2   
> 3       4
> ```

Comment: Thank you for answering, @saastn. Now I can get rid of the headerlines but the final table does not look good. I changed the delimiter but it did not work!. could you please help me more. Thanks.

Comment: I just want to pick columns 5,6,7 from the text.